# is there a way to loop this with global variables?

Tags: javascript

i have global variables in a sequence like (RoastAboutlvl1  RoastAboutlvl2 RoastAboutlvl3 etc...).and i want a loop for global variables

```
if(lvlOfRoast.value == 1){
      if (selector.options[0].selected) {
        window.alert("choose a topic");
      }else if(selector.options[1].selected){
          document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = randomRoast(roastAboutCheapLvl1); // roastAboutCheapLvl1 is a global variable
      }else if (selector.options[2].selected) {
        document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = randomRoast(roastAboutCheapLvl2);// roastAboutCheapLvl2 is a global variable
      }else if (selector.options[3].selected) {
        document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = randomRoast(roastAboutCheapLvl3);// roastAboutCheapLvl3 is a global variable
      }else if (selector.options[4].selected) {
        document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = randomRoast(roastAboutCheapLvl4);// roastAboutCheapLvl4 is a global variable
      }else if(selector.options[5].selected){
        document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = randomRoast(roastAboutCheapLvl5);// roastAboutCheapLvl5 is a global variable
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: You could really do with clarifying the question.  Make the title descriptive of your problem, rather than trying to make it the question, and add more information into your question - state what you expect and what is happening.  Fore more info read **[ask]**

Comment: how am i gonna array global variables

Comment: I understand you're a new user, what do you intend to achieve because your question is not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each `roastAboutCheapLvl#` into an array, and use a select element's `selectedIndex` property instead, so you can access the associated property in the array when the index isn't 0:

```
const arr = [
  roastAboutCheapLvl1,
  roastAboutCheapLvl2,
  roastAboutCheapLvl3,
  roastAboutCheapLvl4,
  roastAboutCheapLvl5
];
if(lvlOfRoast.value == 1){
  const { selectedIndex } = selector;
  if (selectedIndex === 0) {
    window.alert("choose a topic");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("generatedRoast").innerHTML = randomRoast(arr[selectedIndex - 1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: well, the elements of (arr) is not defined

Comment: @mhdHD How are they defined in your original code then?